# Apache module RPAF documentation?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, ip, debian-wheezy

I installed [libapache2-mod-rpaf package](https://packages.debian.org/fr/wheezy/libapache2-mod-rpaf) on Debian because [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html) seems to be not available.

I found a [github repo](https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf) but the configuration options are different. For example, in the repository, `RPAF_Enable` is used, but the default configuration of the package uses `RPAFenable` (see the [default configuration of the package](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/libapache2-mod-rpaf.git/tree/debian/rpaf.conf))

Where can I find the documentation for the module I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub encourages forking.  **The Git repository you cited is a fork that differs from your Debian package.**  Assuming that you are using [libapache2-mod-rpaf for Debian wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libapache2-mod-rpaf), inspect [libapache2-mod-rpaf_0.6-7+wheezy1.dsc](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libapache2-mod-rpaf/libapache2-mod-rpaf_0.6-7+wheezy1.dsc).

```
Format: 3.0 (quilt)
Source: libapache2-mod-rpaf
Binary: libapache2-mod-rpaf
Architecture: any
Version: 0.6-7+wheezy1
Maintainer: Sergey B Kirpichev <skirpichev@gmail.com>
Dm-Upload-Allowed: yes
Homepage: http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/
Standards-Version: 3.9.3
Vcs-Browser: http://git.debian.org/?p=collab-maint/libapache2-mod-rpaf.git;a=summary
Vcs-Git: git://git.debian.org/git/collab-maint/libapache2-mod-rpaf.git
Build-Depends: apache2-threaded-dev, debhelper (>= 9)
Package-List: 
 libapache2-mod-rpaf deb httpd extra
```

First, you may notice that http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/ is a dead link.  It's not clear that the package is well supported upstream.

Next, try inspecting the [Vcs-Browser URL](http://git.debian.org/?p=collab-maint/libapache2-mod-rpaf.git;a=summary), then browse `tree` → `mod_rpaf-2.0.c`.  At [Line 207](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/libapache2-mod-rpaf.git/tree/mod_rpaf-2.0.c#n207), you'll see

```
static const command_rec rpaf_cmds[] = {
    AP_INIT_FLAG(
                 "RPAFenable",
                 rpaf_enable,
                 NULL,
                 RSRC_CONF,
                 "Enable mod_rpaf"
                 ),
    AP_INIT_FLAG(
                 "RPAFsethostname",
                 rpaf_sethostname,
                 NULL,
                 RSRC_CONF,
                 "Let mod_rpaf set the hostname from X-Host header and update vhosts"
                 ),
    AP_INIT_ITERATE(
                    "RPAFproxy_ips",
                    rpaf_set_proxy_ip,
                    NULL,
                    RSRC_CONF,
                    "IP(s) of Proxy server setting X-Forwarded-For header"
                    ),
    AP_INIT_TAKE1(
                    "RPAFheader",
                    rpaf_set_headername,
                    NULL,
                    RSRC_CONF,
                    "Which header to look for when trying to find the real ip of the client in a proxy setup"
                    ),
    { NULL }
};
```

Those are the directives that are relevant for the mod_rpaf 0.6 that comes with Debian wheezy.

Answer (score -2):

Documentation is here:

https://github.com/y-ken/mod_rpaf
https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf

**Example Configuration**

LoadModule       rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so

RPAFenable       On

RPAFproxy_ips    192.168. 10.0.0

RPAFheader       X-Forwarded-For

RPAFsetHostname  Off

RPAFsethttps     Off

RPAFsetport      Off

I dont know Why they remove the underscore in configuration examples but not when they explain settings on main page.

Comment: Re-read my question: the config is not the same for the Debian package. The default config on Debian Wheezy is http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/libapache2-mod-rpaf.git/tree/debian/rpaf.conf , so no configuration option match the configuration options listed on the github repo.

Comment: The only change is the underscore RPAF_Enable = RPAFEnable I setup it on debian and centos and is the same options.

Comment: It's seems all the options are renamed. So what is the options for RPAF_SetHTTPS and RPAF_SetPort ?

Comment: Is the same, whitout underscore and need to put in on lowercase RPAFsethttps and RPAFsetport acording to config, I edited my first response.